# How can I remove the space below the image?

Tags: html, css, image

[image: How can I remove the space below the image?]

How can I remove the space below the image?

Comment: Open MS Paint. And crop it

Comment: use paint or any image editor , you don't need css to edit this kind of issue

Comment: its only when i include in the table then the white space will appear.

Comment: `display: inline-block` adds a annoying space always. and as I know, `img` tags have `display: inline-block` by default. So, remove it by adding `display: block`.

Comment: What has to do with CSS?

Comment: @user3230289 in that case you should include your code

Comment: @PeeHaa you are recommending MS Paint?

Comment: Click here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPXQpW, modify it, show us the problem and then ask normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image is a inline element. you should do this (add `vertical-align`and `display` block element):

```
img{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
display: inline-block
```